# How to create an exchange using rabbitmqctl

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

rabbitmqctl have the subcommand `list_exchanges` to list all the exchanges. How can I create an exchange using rabbitmqctl, as I didn't see the add_exchanges subcommands?

Answer (score 6):

Exchanges **cannot** be created with rabbitmqctl. You can use [rabbitmqadmin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) for that, search for `Declare an exchange` on that link.

Additionally exachages can be created "manually" using the web browser with rabbitmq management plugin, or with [rabbitmq rest api](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/).